# from docusign sdk i am trying to get envelope but getting "Reason: The URL provided does not resolve to a resource." 404 error

Tags: python-3.x, sdk, docusignapi

I am trying to create envelope from SDK but getting error like this

Reason: The URL provided does not resolve to a resource.
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'X-DocuSign-TraceToken': '22dad523-9f77-4b83-9481-1e376faf60d8', 'Date': 'Thu, 05 Dec 2019 13:02:26 GMT', 'Content-Length': '0'})

```
def worker(args):
    """
    1. Create the envelope request object
    2. Send the envelope
    """
    envelope_args = args["envelope_args"]
    #print(args)
    #print("envelope arrrgggsss")
    #print(envelope_args)
    # 1. Create the envelope request object
    envelope_definition = make_envelope(envelope_args)
    #print(envelope_definition)
    # 2. call Envelopes::create API method
    # Exceptions will be caught by the calling function
    api_client = ApiClient()
    api_client.host = args["base_path"]
    print(api_client.host)
    api_client.set_default_header("Authorization", "token" + args["ds_access_token"])

    envelopes_api = EnvelopesApi(api_client)

    results = envelopes_api.create_envelope(args['account_id'], envelope_definition=envelope_definition)
    #print(results)
    envelope_id = results.envelope_id
    app.logger.info(f"Envelope was created. EnvelopeId {envelope_id}")

    return {"envelope_id": envelope_id}
```

Before that i try to get the token from the following code

```
def oauth2_token_request(root_url, username, password,
                             integrator_key):
        url = root_url + '/oauth2/token'
        data = {
            'grant_type': 'password',
            'client_id': integrator_key,
            'username': username,
            'password': password,
            'scope': 'api',
        }
        headers = {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        }
        response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
        print(response)
        if response.status_code != 200:
            raise exceptions.DocuSignOAuth2Exception(response.json())

        return response.json()['access_token']

def oauth2_token_revoke(root_url, token):
        url = root_url + '/oauth2/revoke'
        data = {
            'token': token,
        }
        headers = {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        }
        response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
        return response

        # if response.status_code != 200:
        #     raise exceptions.DocuSignOAuth2Exception(response.json())
```

Comment: what is the exact URL you are calling?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are hitting wrong API endpoint as

```
/restapi/v2.1/accounts/9286679/restapi/v2.1/accounts/9286679/envelopes
```

whereas the correct URI is

```
/restapi/v2.1/accounts/9286679/envelopes
```

check your "base_path" value.